# How to correctly bind a parameter in php mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, where-clause

I'm trying to develop a confirmation system for creating accounts, the thing is that if i put a parameter in the where clause of the statement it doesn't return the desired result, but if i burn the value for which i'm testing it works. So my question is how to correctly set and bind the parameters in a mysql php statement?, here's what i've tried so far:

```
$activation_key = htmlentities($_GET['activation_key']);
$sql_stmt = "SELECT email, activation_key, is_active FROM users WHERE activation_key = :activation_key";

$query_params = array(
    ':activation_key' => $activation_key
);

try
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql_stmt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':activation_key', $activation_key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
};

$row = $stmt->fetch();
print_r($row);
print_r($stmt);
print_r($result);
```

the above code prints the statement and a 1 as a result but doesn't print the row. however if i set the statement to something like

```
$sql_stmt = "SELECT email, activation_key, is_active FROM users WHERE activation_key = 'somekey'";
```

and indeed somekey is in the database, then it runs as i would expect.

EDIT:
 my problem was with my hashing algorithm and the database column length, i  posted my own answer and will mark it in two days as allowed by stack overflow.

Comment: what does `$row` yield?

Comment: What contains $activation_key ?

Comment: tip: always turn on error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
`

Comment: yeah, what does `var_dump($activation_key)` yield before it is bound to the statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
$p = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE activation_key = ?");
$p->execute(array($your_key));
```

Comment: put some explanation to the code posted, this help others.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question, the problem wasn't on how i was binding the parameter, instead it was because my hashing algorithm was trying to store an activation key of which it's length was greater than that of the allowed in the database. I noticed this using var_dump(), thank you guys for your suggestions and sorry for wasting your time.